# How to use a JQuery function twice in the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, accordion

I'm not really great at coding, but I eventually do some stuff for my office.

I'm currently building an accordion that carries some information from a json. I use a JQuery code I got in the internet to build it.

Problem is I'm trying to call this JQuery function twice in the same HTML page, building two different accordion sets with two different json data.

I've tried changing the JQuery, calling one "accordion.init()" and another "accordion2.init(), with several different variations, but didn't succeed.

My html is pretty straight foward:

```
<script src="fase2.js"></script>
<div class="container">
<section class="accordion"></section> 
</div>
```

And the js file that the HTML inherits:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var accordion={
        init:function(){
            this.accordionJson='fase2.json';
            this.getData();
        },
        getData:function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:accordion.accordionJson,
                success:function(data){
                    var dataBlock=data.data;
                    accordion.iterateAccordionData(dataBlock);
                    accordion.hideAccordion();
                }
            });
        },
        iterateAccordionData:function(accordionData){
            for(i=0;i<accordionData.length;i++){
                $(".accordion").append("<article>");
            }
            accordion.appendAccordionContent(accordionData);
        },
        appendAccordionContent:function(accordionData){
            $('article').each(function(index){
                $('article').eq(index).append('<h2><img src= "' + accordionData[index]['Logo'] +'">' + accordionData[index]['FriendlyName'] + '<span> #'+  accordionData[index]['index'] + '</span></h2>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Role</span>:<br>' + accordionData[index]['Roles']+ '</p>')
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>APIs:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['ApiFamilyType']+'</p>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Endpoints:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['ApiEndpoints']+'</p>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Organisation:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['OrganisationName']+'</p>');
            });
        },
        hideAccordion:function(){
            $('p').hide();
            accordion.toggleAccordion();
        },
        toggleAccordion:function(){
            $('article').on('click',function(){
                $(this).find('p').slideToggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
        },
    };
    accordion.init();
});
```

What I have tried to do is calling a second js file, with different names to most of the variables:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
var accordion2={
    init:function(){
        this.accordionJson='fase2-n.json';
        this.getData();
    },
    getData:function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:accordion2.accordion2Json,
            success:function(data){
                var dataBlock=data.data;
                accordion2.iterateAccordionData(dataBlock);
                accordion2.hideAccordion();
            }
        });
    },
    iterateAccordionData:function(accordionData2){
        for(i=0;i<accordionData2.length;i++){
            $(".accordion").append("<article>");
        }
        accordion2.appendAccordionContent(accordionData2);
    },
    appendAccordionContent:function(accordionData2){
        $('article').each(function(index){
            $('article').eq(index).append('<h2><img src= "' + accordionData2[index]['Logo'] +'">' + accordionData2[index]['CustomerFriendlyName'] + '<span> #'+  accordionData2[index]['index'] + '</span></h2>');
            $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Role ITP</span>:<br>' + accordionData2[index]['Roles']+ '</p>')
            $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Família de APIs publicadas:</span><br>'+accordionData2[index]['ApiFamilyType']+'</p>');
            $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Endpoints publicados:</span><br>'+accordionData2[index]['ApiEndpoints']+'</p>');
            $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Organizações que utilizam está marca:</span><br>'+accordionData2[index]['OrganisationName']+'</p>');
        });
    },
    hideAccordion:function(){
        $('p').hide();
        accordion2.toggleAccordion();
    },
    toggleAccordion:function(){
        $('article').on('click',function(){
            $(this).find('p').slideToggle();
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    },
};
accordion2.init();
});
```

But I end up with an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Logo')
> at HTMLElement. (fase2-n.js:25:88)

which is this line:

```
$('article').eq(index).append('<h2>imgsrc="'+accordionData2[index]'Logo']+'">'+accordionData2[index]['CustomerFriendlyName']+'<span>#'+accordionData2[index]['index']+'</span></h2>');
```

This error is making me confused, because if I print something like: `console.log(accordionData2[0]['Logo']`, the js code will give me a positive result for a logo in my json.

Could you help me understand what is incorrect?

obs: the accordion loads properly with only one jQuery being called.
obs2: With the code I posted here, the data from the second json loads together with the first accordion, one accordion on top of another. I imagine the error above only presents itself after the first json data ends (the first json index is smaller than the second)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var accordion={
        init:function(jsonFile){
            this.accordionJson= jsonFile ;
            this.getData();
        },
        getData:function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:accordion.accordionJson,
                success:function(data){
                    var dataBlock=data.data;
                    accordion.iterateAccordionData(dataBlock);
                    accordion.hideAccordion();
                }
            });
        },
        iterateAccordionData:function(accordionData){
            for(i=0;i<accordionData.length;i++){
                $(".accordion").append("<article>");
            }
            accordion.appendAccordionContent(accordionData);
        },
        appendAccordionContent:function(accordionData){
            $('article').each(function(index){
                $('article').eq(index).append('<h2><img src= "' + accordionData[index]['Logo'] +'">' + accordionData[index]['FriendlyName'] + '<span> #'+  accordionData[index]['index'] + '</span></h2>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Role</span>:<br>' + accordionData[index]['Roles']+ '</p>')
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>APIs:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['ApiFamilyType']+'</p>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Endpoints:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['ApiEndpoints']+'</p>');
                $('article').eq(index).append('<p><span>Organisation:</span><br>'+accordionData[index]['OrganisationName']+'</p>');
            });
        },
        hideAccordion:function(){
            $('p').hide();
            accordion.toggleAccordion();
        },
        toggleAccordion:function(){
            $('article').on('click',function(){
                $(this).find('p').slideToggle();
                $(this).toggleClass('active');
            });
        },
    };
    accordion.init('fase2.json');
    accordion.init('fase3.json');
});
```

And then you can have one single function, sending the filename in the init() props. If you need more than one accordion working at the same time, you should replace $("article") to something like $(this).find("article") so the selector will touch only the closest element of the iniciator and not all of them

Comment: Hi Lucio. I understand that I can pass different parameters to my accordion.init, and this seems like the correct way to go. 

The question  that remains is: Can I pass those parameters from the html, so I can call accordion.init('fase2.json') at one <div> of my page, and in another <div> call accordion.init('fase3.json')?

Comment: Yes of course, you can call it by adding: onclick="accordion.init('file.json')" to the element you want to trigger the event. Or just put the name of the json as a prop in the element like: id="fase2", and add a class to every element that triggers the function: class="accordion-push" so then with jquery do: $(".accordion-push").click( () =>{  accordion.init( $(this).attr("id")+".json" )  } );

Comment: Hi Lucio. With some changes I have managed to apply something similar to your ideas. What I did was create an accordion append for each case, and using ids to identify it. This way I can use the core of the function as is in the original code, and only add specific appending for each accordion I need. Thanks for the help!